# toast line is never called

Tags: java, android, toast, listeners

When I press an image on the screen, it calls the powerButton.OnClickListener() like it's supposed to and, after a few seconds of buffering, the stream plays just fine. However, the folks would like a brief toast popup to display to notify the user "Radio Stream Connecting, Please Wait..."

This is where the problem is, no matter what I've tried and where I've placed the line to create the toast popup, it simply will not display before it goes into buffering.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I've added most of the code and will provide more if necessary.

```
        // run on powerButton click
    powerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // check if the player is started or stopped
            if (isPlaying) // player is streaming
            {
                // stop the stream and set isPlaying to false
                mediaPlayer.stop();

                // release the media player
                releaseMediaPlayer();

                // update notification
                mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);

                // set power button to "powered off" image
                powerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.power_off);
            }
            else // player not streaming
            {
                // notify the user that the stream is loading
                final Toast streamLoading = toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Stream Connecting, Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                streamLoading.show();

                // try catch block to attempt connecting to radioUrl
                try
                {                       
                    // create new instance of media player
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                    // set media player to handle audio streams                    
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                    // connect to radio stream and fill buffer
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioUrl);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long depending on buffering speed

                    // start the media player and set isPlaying to true
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    isPlaying = true;

                    // update notification, clear stream message
                    createNotification();

                    // set power button to "powered on" image
                    powerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.power_on);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) // cannot connect to stream
                {
                    // clear streaming text and notify user of failure
                    final Toast streamError1 = Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "Failed to load: Unable to connect to stream!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    streamError1.show();

                    // release the media player and display error
                    releaseMediaPlayer();
                    mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IllegalStateException e) // stream cannot play audio
                {
                    // clear streaming text and notify user of failure
                    final Toast streamError2 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed to load: cannot play stream!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    streamError2.show();

                    // release the media player and display error
                    releaseMediaPlayer();
                    mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) // general connection issue
                {
                    // clear streaming text and notify user of failure
                    final Toast streamError3 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed to Load: Connection issue!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    streamError3.show();

                    // release the media player and display error
                    releaseMediaPlayer();
                    mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the toast won't show until you return from the onClick because that is the UI thread. I You won't do that until after the buffering is started. I think to get the effect you want, you check the AsynchTask to do the buffering in a background thread and return right away from the onClick.

As a matter of fact the way you are doing it, if the buffering takes too long your app will get flagged as non responsive by android.

Comment: "get flagged as non responsive by android." And rightfully so. We're not supposed to do long-lasting tasks on the UI thread. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) where the first thing the AsyncTask does is display the toast before falling into the buffering procedure.